# ng-click / ng-class combination not working as expected with $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

For some reason my `ng-click` / `ng-class` combination is not working. On click the class '`hide`' has to be added based on the equality of the `productDisplay` variable.

```
            <div ng-repeat="product in project.data track by $index">

                <p ng-click="productDisplay = $index"><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></p>

                <div class="fileList" ng-class="{'hide': productDisplay !== $index}">{{$index}}</div>
```

I can click on the `<p>` element and the div `fileList` will open but i can't close them once they are opened.

Any ideas?

thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try toggling instead of going for `$index`, use `productDisplay = !productDisplay` this will change the ng-class expression and apply hide class whenever it gets clicked, or more better code you can use `ng-if`/`ng-show`/`ng-hide` instead of using `ng-class`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in project.data track by $index">

    <p ng-click="productDisplay = !productDisplay"><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></p>

    <div class="fileList" ng-class="{'hide': productDisplay">{{$index}}</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Same thing can be done by maintaining `productDisplay` variable in parent scope of `ng-repeat` then you need to `$parent.productDisplay` inside `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="product in project.data track by $index">

    <p ng-click="$parent.productDisplay = $index"><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></p>

    <div class="fileList" ng-class="{'hide': $parent.productDisplay !== $index">{{$index}}</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not a great 'answer' ;-) it's a great 'alternative' (which i end up using). The answer i was looking for is to use $parent.productDisplay :p

Comment: if you want to maintain an index throughout the page the `$parent.productDisplay` would be good option too..

Comment: great, i checked your answer :-)